# Can the positioning of the navigation bar influence SEO?

Tags: seo, navigation, sitelinks

Placing the navigation bar in the html code not near the head, or even on the bottom to favor the contents *(the users would view the menu as a topbar using flexbox source ordering)*, can improove SEO? Considering that Google Sitelinks are based on the navigation structure, could the same navigation structure be a discriminant to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of the nav bar has no effect on SEO.

According to John Mueller, Google's Senior Webmaster Trends Analyst, the positioning of internal links on a website [do not impact the site's SEO](http://www.thesempost.com/google-position-weight-internal-links-seo/):

> Position on a page for internal links is pretty much irrelevant from our point of view.  We crawl, we use these mostly for crawling within a website, for understanding the context of individual pages within a website.  So if it is in the header or the footer or within the primary content, it’s totally more up to you than anything SEO wise that I would worry about.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my favorite page structure: a few important links, to let Google take them as sitelinks, then content, then all remaining links.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind for the next projects